# Bootstrap Carousel Slide Animation Problem

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

**Hi,**
I've started using Bootstrap and something strange happend,
when i've run the code the controls work fine but there is no animation of slide (like in bootstrap's site)
**This Is The Code**

PLZ HELP
(the code is from app brewery bootcamp so don't laugh at me :) )

```html
<section id="testimonials">
  <div id="test-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img class="test-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="test-img" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#test-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#test-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

iv'e found out what's the problem...
It's only supported in Bootstrap 4.0.0

 and iv'e tried it on 4.4.1